# Thresholding Hansen Forest Cover/Global Forest watch treecover in earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to threshold the treecover2000 layer (i.e., tree cover in year 2000) at 25% using GEE. How would I do that? Below is code I wrote to load the gfc tree cover dataset

```js
var gfcImage = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015');
var treeCover = gfcImage.select(['treecover2000']);
```

Do I have to do something like below?

```js
var treeCover25=gfcImage.select(['treecover2000']).select(0.25);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mask out values less than 25% like this:

```js
var gfcImage = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015');
var treeCover = gfcImage.select(['treecover2000']);
var greater25 = treeCover.gte(25)  // this is a mask

var treeCover_greater25 = treeCover.updateMask(greater25)

Map.addLayer(treeCover_greater25)  // Watch if it is what you need
```

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ae2f5792e1b9df272385d718dd14d6bb